# bgIframe with Superfish, the items are behind Silverlight objects

Tags: jquery, silverlight, superfish, bgiframe

I'm using the Superfish menu and the bgIFrame plugin. I have Silverlight objects on several pages. The menu is beneath the object, even though I've added the bgIFrame like in [this example](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#sample2) (it happens on IE9 and Chrome, I haven't checked the rest of the browsers). I know that you can set IsWindowless to true, but I don't want to do that for a number of reasons.

When I use the ASP.Net Menu control it does appear over the object, so I know it's possible. Is bfIFrame not using IFrame in the correct way to make this happen. Is there an alternative to bgIFrame?

EDIT: I cross posted this on the [Github page](https://github.com/brandonaaron/bgiframe/issues/8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the pull requests on GitHub and [request #7](https://github.com/brandonaaron/bgiframe/pull/7) seems to fix the issue. For now I downloaded the forked version.

Edit: This issue was completed in February, 2013. https://github.com/brandonaaron/bgiframe/issues/8